Massive images in job ad sidepanel
A few times now, I've seen images in the side panel that look like they're probably larger than intended:

I think the "X" button is meant to be small? And the profile image above it seems like it's overflowed (I stupidly changed pages after taking the screenshot so I can't check).
The last time I saw this, there were three of the "X" buttons in a row, all the same size as here. I couldn't even see what they were associated with.
Chrome Version 125.0.6422.113 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Found some more after some refreshing:

And I didn't cut this off on the right.

Looks like some size-restraining CSS isn't being applied, because I can't see any height/width rules on the large elements.

And if I click the huge "X", it sends a POST request to https://clc.stackoverflow.com/click? that 500s.

No repro if you run uBlock ...

I thought at first it was the logo of some company, and the absence of any text was some kind of viral marketing strategy...
